# allocate random float numbers to an array withing a range specified by the user

Tags: c, arrays, random

I do not know where the problem lies

```
int main()
{

    int antalVarde = 0;
    low=0, high=0;
    float* arr;
    srand((int)time(NULL));

    printf("Hur många värden ska skapas: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &antalVarde);
    printf("Ange min-värde: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &low);
    printf("Ange max-värde: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &high);


    arr = (float*)malloc(antalVarde * sizeof(float));

    for (int i = 0; i <= antalVarde; i++)
    {
        *arr = RandomReal(low, high);
    }
    printf("%f", *arr);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}


float RandomReal(float low, float high)
{


    float d;

    d = (float) rand() / ((float) RAND_MAX + 1);
    return (low + d * (high - low));
}
```

Comment: Please describe how what this should do differs from what it actually does.

Comment: conversion from int to float, possible loss of data on line 27
  *arr = RandomReal(low, high);

Comment: Pro-tip: Tags go in tags, not title.

Comment: @PhilipBjärnstig Why are you using `float` in the first place?

Comment: What type your `low` and `high` ? The ones in `main`. Looks like `int`. Why?

Comment: Professor asked us to use float

Answer (score 0):

Your loop control

```
i <= antalVarde;
```

would break the bounds of memory allocation and should be

```
i < antalVarde;
```

However, every random value is written to the *first* address of the memory allocation with

```
*arr = RandomReal(low, high);
```

and all the other locations still contain indeterminate values. So the loop should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < antalVarde; i++)
{
    arr[i] = RandomReal(low, high);
}
```

Finally, the reason for the compiler warning is that there is no function prototype so the compiler has assumed is will be `int` type. So add

```
float RandomReal(float low, float high);
```

above `main()`.